# Why does this only display one of my records?

Tags: php, pagination

I am trying to get pagination working on my website. Everything should be working but this only displays one product, however that should be 8 products. Anybody know what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
else {
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$pages = new Paginator;  
$pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];  
$pages->mid_range = 9;  
$pages->paginate();  

$query = "SELECT serial, name, description, price, picture FROM products WHERE serial != '' ORDER BY serial ASC $pages->limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
{
echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;background-color:#E3E3E3;width:190px;height:200px;"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?serial='.$row[0].'"><img style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;width:150px;height:150px;" src="'.htmlspecialchars($row[4]).'"></a><br><div align="center"><b>'.htmlspecialchars($row[1]).'</b><br><h6>&euro;'.htmlspecialchars($row[3]).'</h6></div></div>';
};
echo '&nbsp;';
echo '<br><br><div style="margin-left:330px;">';
echo $pages->display_pages();
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) only fetches one row at a time. You need to call it repeatedly to display all rows, like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    // handle single row
}
```

I suggest you consider using [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) instead. Then you will not have to rely on the order of the columns anymore and your code becomes more legible:
`$row[0]` becomes `$row["serial"]` etc.

Try reading the articles that @Kush linked. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for a PHP-specific discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to be using [mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) properly

---

The following code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because $page->limit does not appear to be sanitized

```
$query = "SELECT serial, name, description, price, picture FROM products WHERE serial != '' ORDER BY serial ASC $pages->limit";
```

Stop using mysql_* functions as they're deprecated. Use [PHP database objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead because PDO allows parameter binding which protects you from sql injection.

You can read up on using PDO [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score 0):

because of this line

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
```